# changing text color of multiple text strings in same textview

Tags: android, fonts, textview

Is to possible to have changing text color of multiple text strings in the same `TextView`? Using `Html.fromHtml` is not working:

```
textViewPrevChat.append("\n"+Html.fromHtml("<b>Bold string </b>")+somestringhere);
```

It is printing whole thing in bold. Also, the color attribute in `<p>` is not working.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a SpannableString for this.  Here is an example method implementing this:

-This example changes the color of one half of a string, and adjusts the size of another section of the String:

```
public static SpannableString categoryText(String label, String text, int colorIn) {
        String strIn = label + " " + text;
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(strIn);        
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colorIn), 0, label.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.80f), 0, label.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return ss;
    }
```